# How to programmatically resize Remote Desktop window and trigger smart sizing?

Tags: winapi, remote-desktop

I am trying to resize remote desktop window from an external app to a specific size programmatically.

The issue is that when I call `MoveWindow`, while the window jumps into specified coordinates (all without leaving the primary monitor), the session resolution is not adjusted and instead scrollbars appear.

If I resize the window manually by the grip, the resolution of the remote session is adjusted.

I also tried: `SetWindowPos(..., SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS)` with the same result.

Comment: Use [SetMaxXResolution and SetMaxYResolution methods of the Win32_TSClientSetting class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/setmaxxresolution-win32-tsclientsetting).